# I rescued a dog from the street. What haircut should I ask for?

Tags: dogs, grooming, new-pets

I adopted this dog some months ago. I don't know a lot of dogs and stuff. What haircut will suit him?

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Pets! You actually shouldn't cut your dogs hair unless it's matted. I closed this question and linked 2 other questions that provide more details as to why cutting your dogs hair is a bad idea and what problems might arise as a result. If you feel that those linked questions don't answer your question, please leave me a comment or start a discussion on [Pets Meta](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: ok thank you very much! :)